# How to view and copy to clipboard javascript generated source within an iframe from a web browser?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

A website has iframes. One iframe has javascript generated source which I would like to copy to clipboard.

I tried using FF web developer, but "View Generated Source" only shows me the source of the main iframe. And "View Frame Source" only shows the static source, not JS generated.

An example is on fiddle.tinymce.com - how to copy to clipboard the generated source of the lower frame containing the editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any browser (Chrome, FF, IE), go to Inspector mode. Then right click on the root of the document, choose "copy HTML" or something similar, each of the above browsers has one option that copies to clipboard the whole html of the current state of the document, with changes made by Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome.
You can right-click and choose "Inspect elements" to see the actual HTML.

Comment: I know. But I need to text-search and just have a text version of it, save for later.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, press F12 and look at the Network tab. This will show you a list of the files that were downloaded with the page. Right-click on the file you want and you can open it in a new tab and easily grab the source from there.

Comment: I opened Network tab and refreshed the page. There are many css, js gif and so on... files. But there is no iframe content generated by javascript

Comment: Paste the URL of the Iframe into your address bar.

Comment: The iframe url is preview.php?key=kaaab and going to this address gives me the static version of the iframe, with nothin added dynamically by javascript. I need a version which is generated by javascript. This dynamic version can be viewed using inspector, but I need to copy it to a file, e.g. to be able to text search it.